# Upload file to google cloud storage (JAVA)

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, cloud, cloud-storage

I want to  upload a file to Google Cloud Storage following the example provided at official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-java)

```
  public class UploadObject {
      public static void uploadObject(
          String projectId, String bucketName, String objectName, String filePath) throws IOException {
        // The ID of your GCP project
        // String projectId = "your-project-id";
    
        // The ID of your GCS bucket
        // String bucketName = "your-unique-bucket-name";
    
        // The ID of your GCS object
        // String objectName = "your-object-name";
    
        // The path to your file to upload
        // String filePath = "path/to/your/file"
    
        Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();
        BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, objectName);
        BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).build();
        storage.create(blobInfo, Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));
    
        System.out.println(
            "File " + filePath + " uploaded to bucket " + bucketName + " as " + objectName);
      }
    }
```

Nevertheless, I'm getting the error:

**Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Error getting access token for service account: 400 Bad Request {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim."} at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.translate(HttpStorageRpc.java:227)**

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have a look at the guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future questions. It looks like (from the comments) that you have tried some things prior to asking. Including what you have tried (with [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code) can help people help you faster and better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error has two common causes: the clock where you are executing your task is not in sync with NTP (Network Time Protocol), or, you could check how you are handling the refresh tokens and the old tokens. When the number of refresh tokens exceeds the limit, older tokens become invalid. If the application attempts to use an invalidated refresh token, this error is returned. Take a look at this [document](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)

On the other hand, there are other options that could help you to upload a file to Cloud Storage, you can find a very clear [example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-gsutil#upload_an_object_into_your_bucket) about how to do it using Cloud [SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install) through the command:

gsutil cp [OBJECT_LOCATION] gs://[DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME]/

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) you can find more examples.

Comment: thank you! I've already tried this code but when I execute it an error message appears: Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Error getting access token for service account: 400 Bad Request {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim."}  at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.translate(HttpStorageRpc.java:227)

Comment: This error has two common causes: the clock where you are executing your task is not in sync with NTP (Network Time Protocol), or, you could check how you are handling the refresh tokens and the old tokens. When the number of refresh tokens exceeds the limit, older tokens become invalid. If the application attempts to use an invalidated refresh token, this error is returned. Take a look at this document https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2

Comment: Thanks,it works!!  the probleme was in the clock on the local machine is out of sync, so  i juste  turned the 'Set time automatically'

Comment: I'm glad it worked, just as a kind reminder take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers